# Unable to combine and generate reports on cypress

Tags: cypress

I am unable to combine and generate reports of the CLI run on cypress, but when I run the script manually it saves the report

**package.json**
[image: package.json > scripts]

[image: package.json > dependencies]

**config.json**

[image: config]

Comment: The reason it does not generate the report is because I do not have any failing tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `package.json` should look like this

[image]

And `cypress.json` should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Example dependencies should be installed and your package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
  "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.4.0",
  "mocha": "^8.3.2",
  "mochawesome": "^6.2.2",
  "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0",
  "mochawesome-report-generator": "^5.2.0"
}
```

Add reporter settings in cypress.json

```
{
  "reporter": "cypress-multi-reporters",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",
    "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
      "reportDir": "cypress/reports/mocha",
      "quite": true,
      "overwrite": false,
      "html": false,
      "json": true
    }
  }
}
```

Add scripts in package.json file
For Windows -

```
"scripts": {
    "clean:reports": "if exist cypress\\reports rmdir /s/q cypress\\reports && mkdir cypress\\reports mkdir cypress\\reports\\mochareports",
    
    "pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
    "scripts": "cypress run",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/mocha/*.json > cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json",
"generate-report": "marge cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json -f report -o cypress/reports/mochareports -- inline",
    "posttest": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",
    "test" : "npm run scripts || npm run posttest"
 }
```

For macOS/ Linux

```
"scripts": {
    "clean:reports": "rm -R -f cypress/reports && mkdir cypress/reports && mkdir cypress/reports/mochareports ",
    "pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
    "scripts": "cypress run",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/mocha/*.json > cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json",
"generate-report": "marge cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json -f report -o cypress/reports/mochareports -- inline",
    "posttest": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",
    "test" : "npm run scripts || npm run posttest"
  }
```

You can find more details in https://medium.com/tech-learn-share/attach-screenshot-into-mochawesome-html-report-in-cypress-ca3792081474